# Sending the {Return} key in a script file?

Tags: bash, scripts, add-apt-repository

How can I send the Return key in a script file? I am installing all the PPAs from a script, and while it works, currently the addition of each PPA requires user input of the carriage return.

```
#!/bin/bash
add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-5-1
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, you want the `-y` flag added. From `man add-apt-repository`:

> -y, --yes Assume yes to all queries

Answer (score 0):

The comment by [kos](https://askubuntu.com/users/380067/kos) is correct, this is more or less answered at [Auto confirm when running bash scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250861/auto-confirm-when-running-bash-scripts).

**Serg has the right idea forget about passing a carriage return and just pass -y to add-apt-repository.  Just use his answer.**

> -y, --yes             Assume yes to all queries

So your script would look like such;

```
#!/bin/bash
add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

add-apt-repository -y ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-5-1
```

**Carriage Returns from Shell**

Just to clarify how to send a carriage return from a script, there are a lot of options actually.

You could use the [yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)) command which was built to output y along with a newline or an optional argument with newline.  Thus, yes with no argument is a carriage return.  You can pass a carriage return in a script with the commands from your example;

```
#!/bin/bash
yes '' | add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

yes '' | add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-5-1
```

I think echo would work too actually if it's passing a new line, again from your example;

```
#!/bin/bash
echo | add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

echo | add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-5-1
```

Or for more complicated variations you could use [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) even.